# Безопасно ли не синхронизировать доступ к данным?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net

При условии, что используются только условия и инкремент/декремент.
Хочу ускорить работу многопоточного приложения. Интересует насколько это небезопасно в плане возникновения ошибки.

Comment: Если данные используются в разных потоках, то синхронизировать надо. Причём оно очень долго может работать и без синхронизации, но когда произойдёт ошибка, то шансов найти её будет практически ноль.

Comment: А есть способы, которые работают быстрее lock?

Comment: нет, lock - самый быстрый способ синзронизации [пруф.](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)

Comment: Ну в этом пруфе про тормознутость Interlocked (см. ответ @Василий) ничего не говориться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обращение идет только на чтение либо доступ к данным атомарный, то безопасно. В противном случае, возникает возможность плохо предсказуемых гонок.

В случае инкремента, декремента достаточно использовать класс [System.Threading.Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx), который обеспечивает атомарность операций. В этом случае дополнительной синхронизации не требуется.

Comment: Плюс поставил, но. Если работа организована так, что сразу после инкремента/декремента поток проверяет значение (или наоборот -- проверка и по результату, сразу, модификация), то этот вариант, думаю, не подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве альтернативы к программной синхронизации на уровне клиента, можно попробовать применить механизм изоляции транзакций предусмотренной на уровне сервера. Например, если это MS SQL Server то на сервак достаточно перед началом запроса послать ([дока](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

После этого все запросы автоматом станут синхронизированными. Не знаю станет ли от этого быстрее - это вопрос. Можно еще и поиграться с уровнем изоляции транзакций - может поможет.

Comment: Моя программа не общается с БД.

Comment: Упс... - я думал про БД...

Comment: Интересно, на сколько порядков по скорости отличаются эти варианты? Три, четыре, больше?